# Change action of back bar button item

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to change the action of the back bar button item on a specific `UIViewController` in my navigation controller so that it pops to the root view controller. I've tried the following but they don't work:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

and

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(back)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use `func navigationBar(UINavigationBar, shouldPop: UINavigationItem)` from the `UINavigationBarDelegate`?

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton`

Good luck

Comment: This works but doesn't have the back button arrow "<" with it

Answer (score 1):

First of all `backBarButtonItem` action not works because you can only change back button title,take a look question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765162/backbarbuttonitem-doesnt-call-action).

## Solution

In ViewController from which you want to pop to root ViewController you need to set as a delegate of UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
     navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

and implement UINavigationControllerDelegate this method`

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewController.isKind(of:PreviousViewController.self) {
        navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
    }
}
```

If my answer not fit your needs you can check similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios).

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same look and feel of the back button but change the action, see the ViewWillDisappear answer to the question regarding, "Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed" [Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed)

Answer (score -2):

#### This is your solution, just need to set target and selector, nothing more.

```
 private func setNavBar() {
    let item = navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
    item?.target = self
    item?.action = #selector(self.donePressed)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item
}

 @objc private func donePressed() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The back button is getting disappear.